# Аналог имени Тарас

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Есть ли русский аналог украинского имени Тарас?

Comment: Можно еще называть Тараса Ася ну или Тася,у меня брат то мы его все называем Тася,легко запоминающее 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что никакого русского аналога нет и быть не может, поскольку далеко не у всех имен есть соответствия в разных языках. В Этимологическом словаре нашла сейчас, что имя Тарас пришло из греч. языка, где оно звучало Tepatos

Answer (score 2):

Имя Тарас (Тарасий) - общеправославное, в том числе и русское. 
Вообще в отношении канонических имен не следует говорить об их специфичности для какого-то одного языка. В отдельных языках образуются только формы - Арина в русском (каонониническое Ирина), Оксана в украинском (каноническое Ксения) и т.д.

"Тарас"
-
Значение: «Беспокойный, бунтарь, смутьян».

Происхождение: Имя древнегреческое. Покровитель имени — святитель Тарасий, патриарх Константинопольский. По просьбе святого князя Владимира он прибыл из Константинополя на Русь, чтобы крестить народ киевский. Тарасий усердно проповедовал веру Христову и в других областях Руси.
-
(Источник лекго находится поиском. Не знаю, принято ли тут ссылки приводить)